# Can I increase my facebook fan page custome atb width?

Tags: facebook

I've created a facebook fan page and added a custom tab to that page using iFrame method. By default facebook is rendering that tab content with a width of 520px, I want to know is there any setting or method to change that default page width?

Anybody please suggest somesolution to change that default width of the custom tab page.

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** obviously you can't. But if you are okay with scroll-bars then just use them!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ifaour. I'm using the facebook multi-friend-selector in my page for sharing purpose, all my friends are listing fine in my page but after selecting a friend and submitting the content then the page redirection is not happening properly to the corresponding callback URL. I'm getting an error page with a message of 'The page you requested was not found.' which is loading in the iFrame, can you please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: @Siva: Sure just ask a new question, with some code (maybe the canvas url, page tab url) and the redirect uri you are using and explain the problem..etc

Comment: Posted a new question, can you please check and respond for that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230712/redirection-is-not-happening-correctly-after-sharing-an-app-usign-the-multi-frien.