# Redirection is not happening correctly after sharing an app usign the multi-friend-selector

Tags: facebook

I'm using the facebook multi-friend-selector in my facebook page which is loading all my friends in an iFrame. But after selecting a friend from the list and sending an invitation then redirection is not happening correctly to the corresponding callback URL.

I just struck up with this issue, can anybody please help me to fix this issue.

My code for the multi-friend-selector is:

```
<fb:serverfbml>
    <script type="text/fbml">
    <fb:fbml>
    <fb:request-form action="http://gelofactory.com/dev/SPIN/SXSW/share.php" method="POST" invite="true" type="Download" content="Sharing">
    <fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false" bypass="cancel" email_invite="false" import_external_friends="false" actiontext="Share with your friends." cols="3" rows="3" />
    </fb:request-form>
    </fb:fbml>
    </script>
</fb:serverfbml>
```

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting any errors? anyway, here are some suggestions:

1. Please consider using the new [Requests Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)
2. Make sure you are using the Canvas URL in the `action` parameter: `http://CANVAS_URL/path/to/share.php`